# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm stuck with this relationship error:

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id

Am i missing something? Here's my code:

User.php

```
public function schools(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SchoolsList');
}
```

SchoolsList.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My Blade

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ auth()->user()->schools()->id }}" name="school_id">
```

Answer (score -1):

Your **schools** relation is hasMany, and for lazy load you must be use **->users** not **->users()**, Also **auth()->user()->schools** is instance of 
**Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection** you must be change your code similar this

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->schools as $school)
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $school->id }}" name="school_id">
@endforeach
```